# Cannot start Karel the Robot on Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, karel

So as stated in the title I want to start Karel the Robot on Fedora, I installed the openjdk package and tried everything I found without any success. I'm sadly a total beginner on Linux in general so please walk me through here if you know what to do.

Error is:

```
@fedora Downloads]$ java -jar karel.jar
Exception in thread &quot;main&quot; java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can&apos;t load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.11.0.9-4.fc34.x86_64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2648)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1399)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1397)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1396)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.&lt;clinit&gt;(Toolkit.java:1429)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.&lt;clinit&gt;(Font.java:260)
    at b.y.&lt;clinit&gt;(Unknown Source)
    at MainKt.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I learnt about Karel de Robot about 30 years ago. I'm astonished people still use that :-) (well, now I have a robot vacuumcleaner and guess how I called him :-) ).

Comment: Good ol' Karel I suppose, hope he does his job ;)

Answer (score 0):

[This fedora forum post](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/java-cant-find-library/10128) seems to explain how to fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 34 example, with a contemporary version of karel, https://github.com/f7g/karel-release

```
$ git clone https://github.com/f7g/karel-release.git
$ cd karel-release/
$ java -jar karel.jar     ## The karel GUI opens
```

No issues with the available jdk versions, `openjdk version "1.8.0_292"` or `openjdk version "11.0.11+9"` or `openjdk version "16.0.1+9"`

---

Comment: Still the same problem, seems to be a problem with my openjdk installation